# Проверка чисел на четность

Tags: c++, оптимизация, производительность, битовые-операции

Это можно сделать по разному. Но, все же, какой из нижеперечисленных способов получше с точки зрения читабельности  и эффективности?  Можете перечислить еще пару способов?

```
int i{10}, n{};     
// четное ли число?..
cout << boolalpha;
cout << ++n << ".  " << !(i % 2)      << endl  //true
    << ++n << ".  " << (i % 2 == 0)   << endl  //true
    << ++n << ".  " << (~i & 1)       << endl  //1
    << ++n << ".  " << !(i & 1)       << endl  //true
    << ++n << ".  " << ((i & 1) == 0) << endl; //true
```

И необязательный вопрос: почему в третьем варианте выводится `1` а не `true`?

Comment: С точки зрения читаемости лучше всего выглядит `(i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: Еще способ: `(i & ~1 == 0)`

Comment: [Это можно сделать по разному.] Все леди делают это. :-)

Comment: @Abyx, почему код `cout << ++n << ++n;`, компилятор вправе скомпилировать так, как вы указали? Ведь левый операнд оператора `<<` упорядочен перед правым операндом, а значит, прежде чем приступить к вычислению "правого" `++n` он должен сперва вычислить "левый" `++n` и выполнить все связанные с ним побочные эффекты?

Comment: @Abyx, чтобы вычислить "правый" `++n` сперва необходимо вычислить левый операнд оператора `<<`, т.е. сперва необходимо вычислить выражение `cout << ++n`, включая все побочные эффекты. А это не то же самое, что сперва вычислить "левый" `++n`, потом "правый" `++n`, а потом вывести `cout << tmp1 << tmp2;`. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f70ef66918f3ef65).

Comment: @Abyx, и чем же  грозит несколько вызовов  flush?  Какараз это снимает сомнения по поводу порядка вычисления ++n

Comment: @Герман Борисов,  i & ~1  никогда не  равен нулю, если i >1

Comment: но так:  (i ^ 1) & 1 можно

Answer (score 11, accepted):

При оптимизации все это будет считаться одинаково, а при известном при компиляции `i` - и вовсе во время компиляции.

И даже при неизвестном при компиляции `i` будет считаться только один раз - по крайней мере, VC++ именно так и делает, понимая, что все это - записи одного и того же выражения :)

Например, вот такой код

```
n += !(i % 2);
n += (i % 2 == 0);
n += (~i & 1);
n += !(i & 1);
n += ((i & 1) == 0);
```

свелся к

```
not eax
and eax, 1
lea edx, DWORD PTR [rax+rax*4]
```

Т.е. вычислили один раз через `not` и `and`, и умножили на 5 :)

Необязательный ответ - в третьем случае это значение типа `int`, а в остальных - типа `bool`...

Comment: Harry,  мне всегда нравятся ваши ответы и ваше поведение,  но  сейчас вы так здорово ответили на казалось бы  наивный вопрос...  Не ждал такого ответа.

Answer (score -1):

Каждый программер делает на свой вкус. Вот, пожалуйста :

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

template<class T>
static inline   bool oddp(T x){return x bitand 1;}

// и для читаемости

template<class T>
static inline   bool nechetn(T x){return x bitand 1;}

template<class T>
static inline   bool evenp(T x){return not ( x bitand 1 ) ; }

// и для читаемости

template<class T>
static inline   bool chetn(T x){return not ( x bitand 1 ) ; }

int main(){
int i{10}, n{};     
// четное ли число?..
cout << boolalpha;
cout << ++n << ".  " << !(i % 2)      << endl  //true
    << ++n << ".  " << (i % 2 == 0)   << endl  //true
    << ++n << ".  " << (~i & 1)       << endl  //1
    << ++n << ".  " << !(i & 1)       << endl  //true
    << ++n << ".  " << ((i & 1) == 0) << endl //true
        << ++n << ".  " << nechetn(i) << endl
        << ++n << ".  " << chetn(i) << endl;
}
```

и читаемо , и эффективно.

Comment: Точно, что каждый на свой вкус. oddp и evenp понял сразу, а nechetn и chetn - сломал глаза, пока читал :)) Так что повышение читаемости тут явно не для всех :)

Comment: @Юрий Козлов в открытом офисе оставили только русский вариант : ( **ЧЁТН** , **НЕЧЁТ**). Я пока в струе...